# Помогите пожалуйста разобраться одинарными и двойными кавычками

Tags: php

Не могу понять. Почему $row['id'] выделяется дойными кавычками потом одинарными кавычками и ещё выделяется точками с начала и в конце.

```
 echo '<input value=" '.$row['id'].' " />';
```

Comment: Ваш код __вставьте в текст вопроса__. __Не надо__ все пихать в заголовок.

Comment: Вам надо начать с изучения синтаксиса языка html. Далее - с изучения синтаксиса php.

Comment: вы разобрались?

Comment: echo '<input type="checkbox"  value=" '.$row['id'].' "  name="todelete[]" />';

Comment: вот вся строка кода ,то есть здесь  точки объединяют value  с type и name?

Comment: @АлексейАндреев 1. [Теги](http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml/tegi) 2. [Атрибуты тегов](http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml/tegi/atributy-tegov) 3. [Строки](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php) 4. [Строковые операторы](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.string.php)

Answer (score 2):

в данном случае у вас имеется операция конкатенации (объединения) двух строковых литералов и переменой.
Строки заключены в одинарные кавычки `'<inpupt value="'` и `'"/>'`. Таков синтаксис языка, они должны заключаться либо в двойные, либо в одинарные кавычки.
Оператор объединения строк - точка `.`.

так что у вас тут `строка 1`, объединение, переменная `$row['id']`, еще раз объединение, и `строка 2`, а не выделение двойными и одинарными кавычками и точками.

в результате на выходе вы получите нечто вида `<input value="123"/>`. Двойные кавычки, используемые в строках, предназначены для указания значения атрибута.

Comment: За ваш труд `+1`. Но что мешало автору вопроса прочитать всё это в справочнике по ЯП ...

Comment: @Эдуард почему вы думаете, что автор не пытался где-то что-то почитать? я на 90% вопросов про пхп могу так написать, что надо читать документацию.

Comment: Я разобрался,благодарю за помощь